# How to implement a Symfony form with a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, symfony1

I have three tables forming a many-to-many relationship. They are,

```
WebUserRole -> WebUserRolePermission <- WebUserPermission
```

I've just started doing the admin for my `WebUserRole` object (using the `propel:generate-admin`), and I want the form for the `WebUserRole` to list the permissions with a check box next to each.

Now, is there a built in widget/way of doing this properly? Or will it require a bit of manual tinkering? Links to examples/tutorials are very welcome!

Thank you.

Comment: My first question is why are you not using sfGuard :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the widget you're looking for is [sfWidgetFormPropelChoiceMany](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_2/sfWidgetFormPropelChoiceMany) and you construct it with a model to pull the list from:

```
$this->widgetSchema['permissions_list'] => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoiceMany(array('model' => 'WebUserPermission'));
```

If you haven't seen it yet you should really check out the [sfGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin) mentioned by prodigitalson, it is a very robust authentication system with built-in custom permission management.

Comment: That widget sounds like what I'm looking for, cheers. As for the sfGuardPlugin, we use to use it, but our requirements have exceeded what it can offer.